# How do inexperienced members get enough reputation to participate in the chat rooms?

Tags: support, reputation, chat

I recently found out there is a chat room on this site. Previously i had just thought it was forum questions

My question is how do i gain reputation needed to get access to chat rooms

I've tried answering questions in forums but it seems to be above my level to troubleshoot problems. I have 2 sites currently developed at http://digitalgenesis.com.au and http://www.aicm.org.au so i'm not totally useless, thank god

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, i have posted some questions in terms of php pages for mailing lists and such, and have got some decent answers but i'm still confused as a web design trainee.

As a note i have no technical supervisor so asking anybody within my workplace will not help unfortunately. Would appreciate some guidance

Comment: There are no "forum questions"

Answer (score 7):

The simple answer is that participating in the chat rooms is a *privilege* that you don't earn until you have accumulated a sufficient number of reputation points. But that doesn't seem to be your question: you seem to feel like you're missing out on something in chat, since you can't participate.

The chat rooms don't really help you become a better programmer. The information to noise ratio is substantially higher in the chat rooms. In fact, that's probably why they were created in the first place—
to give people a place to "chat" without cluttering up the actual, useful content. Stick with asking questions, answering questions, and *reading* answers that others have given to questions. *That's* how you're going to learn something and better your skills as a programmer.

Coincidentally, in doing so, you will probably acquire at least a handful of reputation points, which will enable you to start wasting time in the chat rooms.

Answer (score 4):

Another valid way to get points is to ask good, insightful questions that others find useful. If those questions are voted up you will get reputation points.

Comment: thanks for the response. i am not intending to spam, but at the moment i have nobody to guide me in this area. i was promised a position as a trainee position back in august and have since not received any training. My job has been purely learning as i go. Thanks for the response, very helpful