# Chat option for freshers in stackoverflow

Tags: support, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can users with less reputation be allowed to chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97859/can-users-with-less-reputation-be-allowed-to-chat)

I remember once when I tried to answer a question and modify my answer, it took a lot of comments to make it. In the case of beginners in stackoverflow, it is not easy always to provide them **EXACT** answers they expect and there is always a need for interaction. After posting some comments, a suggestion to move comments into chat will began appear. Is there any option for starters (having a rep below 20) to participate in chats or some alternate?

Comment: Getting to 20 reputation is not difficult. One good question would get you there.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

If you ask a few questions that come across in day-to-day programming, surely you'll gain the minimum required reputation within minutes. :)

And

If you answer some questions which you find easy, to the best of your knowledge, surely you'll get an upvote in the review process if someone finds out that an effort has been taken to answer that question.

Comment: lets not encourage people to ask duplicate questions...  If a question comes up in day-to-day programming,  that question will most likely have already been asked and answered...

Comment: Hmmm you are correct. That is a point which should be taken into consideration.

Answer (score 5):

Frankly I think the barrier for entering chat is almost too low. 20 rep is very easy to earn and can be done even by trolls or other people not intending to make constructive additions to the site. The site is focused on QnA. Chat is a distraction from that. It serves a purpose, but it should only serve that purpose for people that really do intend to focus on the QnA aspects.

- Ask one good question (or two not very good ones).
- Give one reasonable answer, even to something easy.
- Spend ten or fifteen minutes editing a few posts for clarity.

The main idea is to keep people from flooding the chat with questions that should be on the main site. Often people want to cheat and think they will get an answer faster if they ask in chat instead of posting a full question. **If they can't be bothered to formulate even one real question or provide somebody with an answer to anything, we don't want to be bothered by them in chat.**