# Chat vs. Q&A - How to get their Maximum Advantage?

Tags: discussion, chat, search, fun, fastest-gun

I am very glad that I can get the fastest answers to my (simple) questions in chat rooms.

However, questions and answers in the chat room are not all that easily accessible to people outside the network. Such content would not easily show up in a Google search.

When asking questions on the Q&A though, I find that sometimes I have to wait a while before getting an answer. But with the advantage that both question and answer are well-documented.

How can we address this situation? Would it be an idea to only ask very simple questions in the chat room and more technical questions on the main site? How can we get the most out of both options?

Comment: everybody is welcomed to improve this question

Comment: I find the question a bit hard to understand. Are you asking: *"I sometimes ask questions in chat and quickly get an answer. But those questions and answers are not easy to find for outside users. How we can address that?"*.

Comment: @Bart : yes you make the question to be easier and more understandable

Comment: Okay, I edited your question significantly. Please read through it and verify that it still says what you intended to ask. If not, feel free to roll it back.

Comment: @Bart: Thanks. It becomes better than before. `Q&A = Forum Discussion Room`

Comment: Yeah, generally the community here does not like to be called a "forum" or "discussion room" because we're not one. We're a Q&A. So minor changes there. I think the question is a valid one, even when I don't immediately have an answer.

Comment: In general, questions that can be asked and answered in a chat room often do not make good Q&A questions.  When they do, the participants in the chat room will often steer the asker to the main site, so that they can ask their question there.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for the comment. That is a good advice. It also related and can be combined with http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80464/how-do-inexperienced-members-get-enough-reputation-to-participate-in-the-chat-ro?rq=1